I remember vaguely about this movie - I saw some scenes from here and there during my childhood
The lead role is played by a female in her early 20s (I suppose) ...having name like Kaplan or something. 
The movie shows random scenes like - a bomb explosion when she is outside a hospital. And then she goes from there.. some other scenes... only to identify herself in the climax that she actually died during that explosion when she returns back to the hospital, and finds her remains at the explosion (people gathering in rounds). The thriller keeps the suspense that no one knows that it's her soul that is shown in the movie after the explosion, not herself really.
And she looked actually so beautiful (or so in my memories kind of like Shannyn Sossamon). I saw it around 7-8 years before, I think. And it wasn't a Hollywood movie. I think it was dubbed.
Please just let me know if any one of you guys figure it out.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

It sounds close to Wristcutters: A Love Story. 
It stars Shannyn Sossamon as the character Mikal (kind of close to Kaplan in terms of being an unordinary name). She is in the afterlife, having died. This one is an American movie in English, and not so much suspense. It's established early that the characters are dead in an afterworld devoid of joy.

The trailer can be found here. 
